# Flutter doctor shows nothing even added to the path

Tags: flutter

I downloaded flutter and added to the path in my windows 10 laptop. when I run `flutter doctor` in cmd nothing happens for a long time

Comment: Try run `flutter --version` check if it shows version and dart version,if there is error you need check you have used correct path@Rathees Koneswaran

Answer (score 0):

You should Restart your Window (Machine) and then go to flutter folder when you installed it and just open **flutter_console.bat** file and type below commands

> flutter upgrade

> flutter doctor

hope it helps to you

Comment: thank you @Ravindra S.Patil I changed flutter directry from Dick C to disck E it worked. But I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

**If you wish to run Flutter commands in the regular Windows console, take these steps to add Flutter to the PATH environment variable:**

```
*From the Start search bar, enter ‘env’ and select Edit environment variables for your account.

*Under User variables check if there is an entry called Path:
  -If the entry exists, append the full path to flutter\bin using ; as a separator from existing values.

- If the entry doesn’t exist, create a new user variable named Path with the full path to flutter\bin as its value.
```

you can read  more
[here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Comment: thank you @Gbenga B Ayannuga. I changed flutter directry from Dick C to disck E it worked. But I don't know why